# Trouble sending attr int variable through ajax, to php, to db column

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Probably the longest way around though I think it originated from an example somewhere.
The div's data-num, which I'm not sure I can use after reading about this some more,

```
div class='bill_like' data-num="1"
```

is used as a variable in the javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.bill_like').click(function() {
 var TriggerClick = 0;
 var id = $(this).attr('data-num');
    if(TriggerClick==0){
        TriggerClick=1;
        request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/bill_like_up.php',
            data: id
        });
        $(this).children( '.vote_label' ).children('.vote_up_image').attr('src', "img/vote_up_green.png");
    }else{
        TriggerClick=0;
        request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/bill_like_down.php',
            data: id
        });
        $(this).children( '.vote_label' ).children('.vote_up_image').attr('src', "img/vote_up.png");
        };
    });
        return false;
});
```

which then passes the data (assuming it does), to this .php.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, bill_like FROM ausdb WHERE id='$id'");
 $sql = "UPDATE ausdb SET bill_like = bill_like + 1 WHERE id='$id'"; 
 $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error()." in ".$sql);
?>
```

The picture changes as it should but there is no update on the db. There are a number of variants on this for different elements in the html in the same file. Does the data-num value need to be different for each one, like a unique id? Should I be using an `<a href="">` to access the javascript? I'm not sure why this isn't working. Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/bill_like_down.php',
        data: {data-id : id } 
    });
```

And server side retrieve using $_POST['data-id'].
That should help. Also note if the id is integer then your Update and select statement should be like below.

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, bill_like FROM ausdb WHERE id=$id");
 $sql = "UPDATE ausdb SET bill_like = bill_like + 1 WHERE id=$id";
```

There is no need of single qoutes as it will treat id as string.

Comment: Ok this was the best answer but it still hasn't resolved the issue I'm facing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your bill_like field INT ?

Comment: Yes, bill_like, int(11), NULL: No, Default:None (own formatting)

Comment: edited the answer check your select and update both.

Comment: check echo your id and check console if your getting the right id. Els there must be some issue with table name or some other issue.

Comment: This has helped a lot! Thanks so much, it's working now!

Answer (score 2):

you just miss by bit, you are using `$_POST['id']` so you have to send **id** in post request

```
 data: {id:id},
```

also i think if their is just one parameter then you can you same ajax call without any change and update `$_POST['id'] to $_POST`. i am not sure about this. but logically it should work.

change your query to `"SELECT id, bill_like FROM ausdb WHERE id='".$id."'"`(if you want parentheses for id else remove single quote )

Answer (score 1):

pass data like below in java script ajax method

```
 data: {id:id}
```

recieve it by `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Appreciate your reply, this hasn't worked unfortunately though it'll be good to have the proper syntax now. Thank you.

Comment: This is the format of data { name: "John", time: "2pm" }

Answer (score 1):

No need to have confusion due to `id` , so use

```
var idDataNum = $(this).attr('data-num');
....
```

And in ajax

```
 data: {id:idDataNum}
```

In sql you dont need single quote around id , so use

`UPDATE ausdb SET bill_like = bill_like + 1 WHERE id=$id`